# (rudin theorem 3.17) Struggling understanding a part of the proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need help understanding a part of the proof of Theorem 3.17 in Rudin Real Analysis

The full theorem can be found here:
[Is Rudin being redundant in this proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039855/is-rudin-being-redundant-in-this-proof)

The problem is on this part

> If $s^* = -\infty$, then $E$ contains only one element, namely $-\infty$, and there is no subsequential limit. Hence, for any real $M$, $s_n > M$ for at most a finite number of values of $n$, so that $s_n \rightarrow -\infty$.

The answer to the question in the link was basically this: " if E were empty, then you would still have that its supremum is −∞", which makes sense. The part I am struggling with is how this proves that $-\infty$ is in the set.

My understanding:
If $s^* = -\infty$ then there are no subsequential limits(either the set $E$ is empty or that it has only the $ -\infty$ element). Thus for any real $M$, $s_n > M$ for at most a finite number of values of $n$. This holds as if it were infinite number of values of $n$, then we could construct a subsequence that $s_{n_k} \rightarrow \infty$, which will be a contradiction to $s^* = -\infty$. now this allows us to have finite\infinite number of values of $n$ for all real numbers $M$ such that $s_n \leqslant M$ thus $s_n = -\infty$ ,but as we are dealing with sequences which contains infinite terms, thus $s_n = -\infty$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ thus we can form a sequence of $-\infty$ terms thus $s_n \rightarrow -\infty$

Does my reasoning work? I would really appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

$s_n \leq M$ for all but finitely many $n$ does not give you $s_n =-\infty$. $(s_n)$ is a sequence of **real** numbers so no $s_n$ can be $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

What you have to notice is $s_n \leq M$ holds for $n \geq n_0$ with $n_0$ depending on $M$. Though $M$ is arbitrary $n_0$ keeps varying with $M$ and you will never get $s_n=-\infty$.

Comment: ok thank you I see the error that I made there.